# How to link between modules from different sections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, documentation, gruntjs

As you may see below, I've defined two sections in the ngdocs setting in my Grunfile.js:

```
ngdocs: {
  options: {
    dest: 'docs',
    html5Mode: false,
    ....
  },
  api: {
    src: ['src/lib/*.js'],
    title: 'Libraries'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['src/app/*.js'],
    title: 'Application'
  }
},
```

How can I connect these modules via `@link` directive? If you build the example, you will see that all links between src/app/main.js module (MainModule) to `src/lib/notification.js` module (`NotificationsModule`) are broken :(

This issue has been repeated from the project issue#98 (https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs/issues/98).

Answer (score 2):

adding module name as prefix solve the problem! that means

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name MainModule.NotifyCtrl
 * @requires $scope
 * @requires api/NotifyModule.NotificationsService
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly, but when writing docs for my services I dicovered that to link to docs in other section of the docs, one needs to use this format:

```
@ngdoc service
@name app.module.servicename
@requires app.module.anotherService
@requires app.module2.anotherServiceInApp
@requires ./api/api.serviceModule.serviceInApiModule
```

note how you need to use relative paths to get from the app documentation to the api documentation